# skip_sum function getting error when input odd integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

So I created this function below.

```
def skip_sum(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    return n + skip_sum(n-2)
```

Anytime I input an odd number as in i get an infinite amount of errors but It does not specify why. Why is it incorrect and how does this bug change my function?

Comment: Suppose I do `skip_sum(1)`. Do you expect any recursive call to hit `n == 0`?

Comment: @user2357112 No. So it is causing the error because every even number would eventually hit 0 but any odd wouldnt? Then what would the function do?

Comment: What is the function supposed to return for odd numbers? When is the recursion supposed to stop?

Comment: What would the function do? Look at the name of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Change `if n == 0:` to `if n <= 0`.  If you have an odd number, say 3, it will drop by two but will never be 0.  The first time it will be 3, the second time it will be 1, and the third time it will be -1, but it will never be 0.